# EntityFramework getting timeout when executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5

I am trying to run a simple stored procedure on my SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I am running the procedure using the Studio Management, I get an answer after less than a second, when running using EF, I get timeout exception after 2 minutes (I set the CommandTimeout to 2 minutes).

When I am using LINQ it works good, but I prefer Stored Procedures.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Please show the code where sproc is called.

Comment: THIS WORKS: 
allCountries = db.AllEvents.Where(x => x.cID == 6046).Select(x => x.CountryID).ToList();
THIS DOESNT:
allCountries = db.GetLocationsBySport(6046).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

When I run it straight on the DB, it works perfect!

Comment: As asked below, does the second query actually get to the database? You sure that no exceptions are thrown?

Answer (score 0):

that sounds odd, specially because EF makes very optimized queries according to your Linq statement, try to use SQL profiler to see the commands sent to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you will need MultipleActiveResultSets=True in your connection string with Entity Framework when you're using SQL Server editions other than Compact. This could be your problem.  Also, as others have suggested, have you checked SQL Profiler to see what code is being sent to the database?